# Set Physical Path in Web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to upload a file in a physical path such as "Servername\FolderName".

How to set that path in Web.Config in appsetting section

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="FilePath" value="" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: `\\SERVERNAME\FolderName$`?

Comment: <add key="FilePath" value="c:\MyFolder" /> ?